# Getting only Last items in the List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I Have foreach loop to retrieve the list items like:

```
//Gets the all the records of the Employee,    
var emps = (from n in db.TIMESHEETs
            where n.Empid_ID == 123
            select n);
//gets the number of the records , ex: no. of the records are 2.
int count = emps.Count();//ex: count = 2

//Timesheet model class contains all get and set properties as below

List<Timesheetmodel> list = new List<Timesheetmodel>();
objts.GetTimeSheetDetails = list;
if (emps.Count() > 0)
{
    Timesheetmodel model=new Timesheetmodel()
    foreach (Timesheet ts in emps)
    {
        //from model class     //from Database "Timesheet" Table
        model.PROJ_ID =          ts.PROJ_ID;
        model.SUN_HRS =          ts.SUN_HRS;
        model.MON_HRS =          ts.MON_HRS;
        model.TUE_HRS =          ts.TUE_HRS;
        model.WED_HRS =          ts.WED_HRS;
        model.THU_HRS =          ts.THU_HRS;
        model.FRI_HRS =          ts.FRI_HRS;
        model.SAT_HRS =          ts.SAT_HRS;
        objts.GetTimeSheetDetails.Add(model);
        //HERE ADDING ONLY LAST RECORD OF THE TABLE. I WANT TO ADD ALL THE RECORDS OF THE TABLE BUT ONLY LAST RECORD IS ADDING TO THE LIST
    }
    return View("Timesheet", objts);// RETURNING ONLY LAST RECORD OF THE DATABASE TABLE
}
```

The problem is when I getting values of the record from the database, and adding to list, only last record is adding, but not all the records of the table.

What is the solution for this. please help me anyone.

Comment: you need to initialize the model variable inside the foreach loop. Else you keep updating the same variable in each iteration of the loop and so the same objects gets updated.

Comment: If the TimeSheets table gets updated frequently then you should change the first line as var emps = (from n in db.TIMESHEETs
                            where n.Empid_ID == 123
                            select n).ToArray();... This will ensure that the select query executes only once... In your code the select query executes once when you get the count(), once again when you iterate it with foreach

Comment: Yes, That's right. it is working, Thanks to you both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code change

```
       if (emps.Count() > 0)
       {
            Timesheetmodel model=new Timesheetmodel()
            foreach (Timesheet ts in emps)
            {
                //from model class     //from Database "Timesheet" Table
                model.PROJ_ID =          ts.PROJ_ID;
                model.SUN_HRS =          ts.SUN_HRS;
                model.MON_HRS =          ts.MON_HRS;
                model.`enter code here`TUE_HRS =          ts.TUE_HRS;
                model.WED_HRS =          ts.WED_HRS;
                model.THU_HRS =          ts.THU_HRS;
                model.FRI_HRS =          ts.FRI_HRS;
                model.SAT_HRS =          ts.SAT_HRS;
                objts.GetTimeSheetDetails.Add(model);
                //HERE ADDING ONLY LAST RECORD OF THE TABLE. I WANT TO ADD ALL THE RECORDS OF THE TABLE BUT ONLY LAST RECORD IS ADDING TO THE LIST
            }

          }
```

to

```
 if (emps.Count() > 0)
 {

            foreach (Timesheet ts in emps)
            {
              Timesheetmodel model=new Timesheetmodel()
                //from model class     //from Database "Timesheet" Table
                model.PROJ_ID =          ts.PROJ_ID;
                model.SUN_HRS =          ts.SUN_HRS;
                model.MON_HRS =          ts.MON_HRS;
                model.`enter code here`TUE_HRS =          ts.TUE_HRS;
                model.WED_HRS =          ts.WED_HRS;
                model.THU_HRS =          ts.THU_HRS;
                model.FRI_HRS =          ts.FRI_HRS;
                model.SAT_HRS =          ts.SAT_HRS;
                objts.GetTimeSheetDetails.Add(model);
                //HERE ADDING ONLY LAST RECORD OF THE TABLE. I WANT TO ADD ALL THE RECORDS OF THE TABLE BUT ONLY LAST RECORD IS ADDING TO THE LIST
            }
  }
```

Comment: Sorry..!! It is not working. I think it is not problem with object creation, because adding first record perfectly, problem is with list behaviour , is't adds items with object dynamically @Ash

Comment: @Sanjay Try adding model object to list and then to objts.GetTimeSheetDetails. Check list object if it contains records.

Comment: No problemo. Keep coding!

Answer (score 1):

you should create a new instance from Timesheetmodel inside the foreach loop like this :

```
if (emps.Count() > 0)
            {

                foreach (Timesheet ts in emps)
                {
                    Timesheetmodel model=new Timesheetmodel();
                    //from model class     //from Database "Timesheet" Table
                    model.PROJ_ID =          ts.PROJ_ID;
                    model.SUN_HRS =          ts.SUN_HRS;
                    model.MON_HRS =          ts.MON_HRS;
                    model.TUE_HRS =          ts.TUE_HRS;
                    model.WED_HRS =          ts.WED_HRS;
                    model.THU_HRS =          ts.THU_HRS;
                    model.FRI_HRS =          ts.FRI_HRS;
                    model.SAT_HRS =          ts.SAT_HRS;
                    objts.GetTimeSheetDetails.Add(model);

                }
            }
```